# Is $A\mapsto \operatorname{tr}( A \rho)$ WOT continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\rho$ be a nonnegative linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$ with $\operatorname{tr}(\rho)=1$. Then is  $A\mapsto \operatorname{tr}( A \rho)$ WOT continuous on the space of bounded linear operators $L(H)$?

EDIT:

- By WOT, I mean weak operator topology.
- I can prove that $A\mapsto \operatorname{tr}( A \rho)$ is sequentially WOT-continuous. However, I can’t seem to prove WOT-continuity

Comment: What does WOT continuous mean?

Comment: "WOT continuous on H" makes no sense that I can see, because WOT is not a topology on $H$.